# How to show row total and column total in crosstab?

Tags: json, jasper-reports, crosstab

I have below json for weekly purchase. Crosstab is used to show weekly purchase of each products. There is target field which is included as rowgroup in the crosstab . When i total targets and weekly the calculation of total target is incorrect.

How can we get total of totals?

sample json.

```
{
    "header": {
        "columnName": [
            "Product Store1",
            "location"
        ],
        "values": [{
                "purchase": {
                    "id":"purchase1001",
                    "name": "bags",
                    "location": "MainMarket "
                },
                "targets":{
                    "weekly":300
                },
                "weekSpend": [{
                        "weekStartDate": 20181105,
                        "spend": 100

                    },
                    {
                        "weekStartDate": 20181112,
                        "spend": 200

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "purchase": {
                    "id":"purchase1002",
                    "name": "shoes",
                    "location": "MainMarket "
                },
                "targets":{
                    "weekly":400
                },
                "weekSpend": [{
                        "weekStartDate": 20181105,
                        "spend": 100

                    },
                    {
                        "weekStartDate": 20181112,
                        "spend": 200

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried following this link https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/incorrect-crosstab-row-group-total-arising-dataset-created-using-right-outer-join
But creating group using product name is giving compilation error.

JRXML that has error total

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="XTabReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="33c43d53-f9b3-4cc9-92b2-bedd805d66a9">
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="XTabDS" uuid="9911fa6c-61b7-4952-81bf-4666e3e17fcf">
        <field name="weekStartDate" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="weekStartDate"/>
        </field>
        <field name="spend" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="spend"/>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.name"/>
        </field>
        <field name="location" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.location"/>
        </field>
        <field name="target" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.targets.weekly"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="listSubDataset" uuid="01e76955-f29e-4d52-991b-aa0149bfdb37">
        <field name="colName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="[0]"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="58">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="10" width="280" height="30" uuid="c8e3d7ad-eeb0-4cd1-8bef-88874e6921d4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[List inside Crosstab]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="560" height="70" uuid="79f2afae-ac8b-4442-ac8e-ae1b1f68109f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.header" value="Crosstab_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.group" value="Crosstab_CG"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.total" value="Crosstab_CT"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.detail" value="Crosstab_CD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <crosstabParameter name="listDS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("header.columnName")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="XTabDS" uuid="73b2e155-5015-451a-8813-7e2ed2f731fb">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("..values..weekSpend.*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                </crosstabDataset>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="412c6db7-0cfa-4025-80cd-8c450f9eab96">
                                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="listSubDataset" uuid="a911c80f-a0b3-4395-bbd7-2c52c67585d3">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{listDS}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="30" width="90">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="168fd030-81cf-4b80-9766-6f4637c779ec"/>
                                        <box>
                                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        </box>
                                        <textElement>
                                            <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{colName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="name" width="90" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="e8aa37d7-0921-40a6-8aca-1cccae61d26d"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="182" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="ff76ebdd-1c14-4924-8bff-392beb7ef1b3"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{totaltargets}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="location" width="90" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{location}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="86107a55-79be-4170-a2ee-b2a0ae5315e2"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{location}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG"/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="target" width="90">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{target}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="3c9c5be2-4ced-4db6-8dd2-0f411281cce6"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{target}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="e14fddff-9658-4dcf-b6a7-78e195e2bba4"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total target]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="weekStartDate" height="30" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{weekStartDate}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="c65fb64a-d89b-4cc3-be28-d76624cb3d93"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{weekStartDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="spend_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{spend}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="totalspend_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{spend}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="totaltargets" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{target}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="efb4b6dd-d9d3-4520-a94e-c0010a572b29"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{spend_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="0" rowTotalGroup="location">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="0" rowTotalGroup="location" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20" rowTotalGroup="name">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="9dbc6e03-7cac-4daa-af1a-a8b7b3b6b97c"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{totalspend_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" rowTotalGroup="name" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20" rowTotalGroup="target">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" rowTotalGroup="target" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The output with wrong totals:

[image]

Comment: [Crosstabs Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/crosstabs/index.html)

Comment: With below steps this issue is now resolved Thanks Alex for the documentation reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get total for row columns by defining group name in the data set used by crosstab.

Below is the final layout

[image]

Below is the modified jrxml notice the data set XTabDS has a group tag for id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="XTabReport" pageWidth="1000" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="960" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="33c43d53-f9b3-4cc9-92b2-bedd805d66a9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="release\AOS 19.4\SampleAdapter.xml"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="XTabDS" uuid="9911fa6c-61b7-4952-81bf-4666e3e17fcf">
        <field name="weekStartDate" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="weekStartDate"/>
        </field>
        <field name="spend" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="spend"/>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.name"/>
        </field>
        <field name="location" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.location"/>
        </field>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.purchase.id"/>
        </field>
        <field name="target" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^{2}.targets.weekly"/>
        </field>
        <group name="namegroup">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="listSubDataset" uuid="01e76955-f29e-4d52-991b-aa0149bfdb37">
        <field name="colName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="[0]"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="58">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="10" width="280" height="30" uuid="c8e3d7ad-eeb0-4cd1-8bef-88874e6921d4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[List inside Crosstab]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="315" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="640" height="250" uuid="79f2afae-ac8b-4442-ac8e-ae1b1f68109f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.header" value="Crosstab_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.group" value="Crosstab_CG"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.total" value="Crosstab_CT"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.crosstab.style.detail" value="Crosstab_CD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <crosstabParameter name="listDS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource">
                    <parameterValueExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("header.columnName")]]></parameterValueExpression>
                </crosstabParameter>
                <crosstabDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="XTabDS" uuid="73b2e155-5015-451a-8813-7e2ed2f731fb">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("..values..weekSpend.*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                </crosstabDataset>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="270" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="412c6db7-0cfa-4025-80cd-8c450f9eab96">
                                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal" ignoreWidth="false">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="listSubDataset" uuid="a911c80f-a0b3-4395-bbd7-2c52c67585d3">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{listDS}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="30" width="270">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="0" y="0" width="270" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="168fd030-81cf-4b80-9766-6f4637c779ec"/>
                                        <box>
                                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                        </box>
                                        <textElement>
                                            <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{colName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="location" width="90" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{location}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="40" uuid="3f1ee208-60d1-412a-9138-7de26110367c"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{location}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="1e206bac-b8b9-4e65-8d12-57881505a4b2"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="name" width="90">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="40" uuid="e8aa37d7-0921-40a6-8aca-1cccae61d26d"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="182" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="ff76ebdd-1c14-4924-8bff-392beb7ef1b3"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="target" width="90">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{target}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="40" uuid="3c9c5be2-4ced-4db6-8dd2-0f411281cce6"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{target}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" uuid="e14fddff-9658-4dcf-b6a7-78e195e2bba4"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total target]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="weekStartDate" height="30" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{weekStartDate}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="c65fb64a-d89b-4cc3-be28-d76624cb3d93"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{weekStartDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="spend_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{spend}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="totalspend_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{spend}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="totaltargets" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{target}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="TOTAL" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$V{namegroup_COUNT} == 1 ? $F{target} : 0]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="40">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="40" uuid="efb4b6dd-d9d3-4520-a94e-c0010a572b29"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <paragraph leftIndent="3" spacingBefore="3"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{spend_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="40" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20" rowTotalGroup="name">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" rowTotalGroup="name" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20" rowTotalGroup="target">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" rowTotalGroup="target" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="90" height="20" rowTotalGroup="location">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="8c4215e9-f710-45ea-84a1-3a5c0adc6619"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{totalspend_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="20" rowTotalGroup="location" columnTotalGroup="weekStartDate">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT"/>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```